# How can I split a variable by line in TCL?

Tags: list, indexing, split, tcl

I have a variable named "results" with this value:

```
{0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3054 11013}
{0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 13 15}
{0.000 3272.744 12702.352 30868.696}
```

I'd like to store each line (values between the '{}') in a separate variable and then, compare each of the elements of each line with a threshold (this threshold will be different for each line, that's why I need to split them).

I've tried

```
set result [split $results \n]
```

But it doesn't really give me a neat list of elements. Any to get 3 lists from the variable "results"?

Comment: What do you mean by "neat list of elements"; what do you consider neat?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think its better to split according to new line character and then apply regexp to fetch the data. I have tried a sample code.

```
set results "{0 0 0 0 1}
{2 2 3 3 3}
{1 1 2 3 4}";
set result [split $results \n];
foreach line $result {
if {[regexp {^\s*\{(.+)\}\s*} $line Complete_Match Content]} {
puts "$Content\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is what I was looking for! :)

Comment: While the solution might match the OP intention, it is overly complicated. `split` and `regexp` are not required.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and the representation of your exemplary data is accurate, then you do not have to process (`[split]`) the data held by `results`, but leave that to Tcl's list parser. In other words, the input is already a valid string representation of a Tcl list eligible for further processing. Watch:

```
set results {
    {0 0 0 0 1}
    {2 2 3 3 3}
    {1 1 2 3 4}
};

set thresholds {
    3
    2
    1
}

lmap values $results threshold $thresholds {
    lmap v $values {expr {$v >= $threshold}}
}
```

This will produce:

```
{0 0 0 0 0} {1 1 1 1 1} {1 1 1 1 1}
```

Background: when `$results` is worked on by `[lmap]`, it will be turned into a list automatically.

Comment: What if there are more than three lines in results? Will you keep updating the thresholds value?

Comment: Well, this is a question to be addressed to the OP, I'd say: "this threshold will be different for each line"? The point of the exercise is more to show that the value held by `results` can be directly used as a list, no need for preprocessing.